# Best Functional Programming Resources?

Tags: functional-programming

What are the best resources (language, books, software) for learning how to become an expert in functional programming and any ideas how useful functional programming is in general?

Answer (score 4):

A great tutorial to learn Haskell basics and thus functional programming basics is "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good":
http://learnyouahaskell.com

Comment: +1 The name of that tutorial made me chuckle :)